# how can I add an element in an XML using SAX parser?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sax

I am using SAX parser for parsing my XML file. I want to add a new element like this.

```
enter code here
<data>
<accounts>
    <account id="1">
        <firstName>aaaa</firstName>
        <lastName>bbbb</lastName>
        <accountNumber>12342344</accountNumber>
    </account>
</accounts>
```

I want to make my the upper xml to this:

```
enter code here
<data>
<accounts>
    <account id="2">
        <firstName>hgff</firstName>
        <lastName>lfghdf</lastName>
        <accountNumber>2344</accountNumber>
    </account>
                   <account id="1">
        <firstName>asdf</firstName>
        <lastName>gen</lastName>
        <accountNumber>144</accountNumber>
    </account>
</accounts>
</data>
```

Answer (score 2):

A SAX parser provides an event driven framwork to parse your xml file. By that I mean take an xml file helps you extract the info into your internal storage. It does not help you with generatring xml. DOM parser framworks generally do have xml generating functionality. A SAX parser, having no internal storage of its own, does not.

Comment: so do i have to shift to DOM, just to implement adding? Or Can i use both? Is it possible to use both parser's in one class?

Comment: for this, a DOM parser will be simpler but there is nothing stopping you generating your own xml from internal storage.

Comment: after generating it using DOM can i parse it using SAX? the SAX implementation of finding strings on XML is much faster and easier.

Comment: Once the data is in  the DOM just get the data out the DOM parsing is about taking a flat text file and turning it into a data structure the computer can manipulate.

Answer (score 1):

Using SAX is very efficient but very labour-intensive in terms of programming effort. It's not clear to me whether you are aware of this.

It's certainly easy enough to achieve this transformation in a SAX filter, and it's not clear to me why you are finding it difficult. Perhaps you need to do more reading: Elliotte Rusty Harold's book on Java and XML, if I remember right, has an excellent chapter on writing SAX applications.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the SAX Parser actually provides an attribute list in  the aphabetic order rather than in the order of original element inserted using:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(newElement), new StreamResult(writer));
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(writer.toString().getBytes());
saxParser.parse(is, handler);
```